# unable to close InfoWindow using infowindow.close()

Tags: google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am build an ionic 2 application using google map. Trying to close the infowindow once user click outside the infowindow. See lots of example using `infowindow.close()` but not sure why i could not apply it.

Error message `property 'close' does not exist on type never`.

**typescrip**

```
  prev_infowindow: boolean = false;

  addInfoWindow(){

  this.http.get(this.baseURI)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {

    let infoData = data;
      let content = "<ion-item>" + 
     "<h2>" + infoData.Title + "</h2>"

 let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

 content: content

 });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {

  if( this.prev_infowindow ) {
   this.prev_infowindow.close(); // error message occurs
 }

this.prev_infowindow = infoWindow;
infoWindow.open(this.map, marker); 
  });

});

}
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to do `infoWindow.close()` instead of `this.prev_infoWindow.close()`? What is `prev_infoWindow` for? It's not used in your code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `this.prev_infowindow` to `false` with the below statement:

```
if(this.prev_infowindow = false ) {
   this.prev_infowindow.close(); // error message occurs
}
```

Assigning `this.prev_infowindow` to `false` makes the `if` condition to be never executed. TypeScript smartly infers this error.

You should use `==` or `===` for comparison.

---

Another this is that you have typed `prev_infowindow` as `boolean` which does not have the `close` method.

If you wanted this to hold the `InfoWindow`, type it as such.  Or type it as `any` if you don't have the type definitions for `InfoWindow`:

```
prev_infowindow: InfoWindow;
// OR
prev_infowindow: any;
```

Comment: Hi, the i tried your answer, the error message changed to `property 'close' does not exist on type false.` and if i change `this.prev_infowindow == true` the error message became `property 'close' does not exist on type true.`